# double free or corruption (out) error with PCL

Tags: ros2, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

System used: ROS2 foxy on Ubuntu 20.04 with PCL 1.10 installed on amd64 architecture.

I have created a C++ subscriber for ROS2 topic `velodyne_points` of the message type `sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2`. Since, this is ROS2 message and PCL can't handle it. So, I first convert it to something (`pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud;`) which PCL can understand using `pcl_conversions::toPCL(*msg, cloud);` where `msg` is the pointer to ROS message and cloud contains the converted PCL data. Then, I want to apply PCL's `voxelGrid` functionality. Since `voxelGrid.setInputCloud(cloudPtr);` takes the argument as a pointer(**the const boost shared pointer to a PointCloud message**), I create one which points to PCL "cloud" using `pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloudPtr (&cloud);`, process it further and save the result in a memory location pointed by `cloud_filtered`. But as soon as program reaches the end of this subscriber callback function, it gives an error `double free or corruption (out)` on the terminal and execution stops (No error in compilation, only in execution).

I tried to understand this error but I am not trying to free some pointer explicitly which is already free. This issue happens because of the line `pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloudPtr (&cloud);` because when I tried commenting this line and the voxelization steps, execution worked well. But I need to do voxelization and some more steps after it is done (ground plane segmentation, clustering etc.).

I am trying to build ROS2 package and run the executable using this command : `clear && colcon build --packages-select custom_nav_stack_pkg --symlink-install && source install/local_setup.bash && ros2 run custom_nav_stack_pkg cpp_executable` which looks fine to me.

Here is the code.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp"
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/PCLPointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl/conversions.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>

class MinimalSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
    MinimalSubscriber()    //Constructor which has the same name as that of class followed by a parentheses. A constructor in C++ is a special method that is automatically called when an object of a class is created. 
    : Node("minimal_subscriber")
    {
      subscription_ = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>
      ("velodyne_points", 10, std::bind(&MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

  private:
    void topic_callback(const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr msg) const
    {
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I received the message , height is: '%d'", msg->height); //
      pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud;
      pcl_conversions::toPCL(*msg, cloud);

      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I received the PCL message , height is: '%d'", cloud.height);
     
      std::cerr << "PointCloud before filtering: " << cloud.width * cloud.height 
             << " data points (" << pcl::getFieldsList (cloud) << ")." << std::endl;

      
      // Declaring pointer for the PCL "cloud" 
      pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloudPtr (&cloud);

      // define a new container for the data
      pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloud_filtered (new pcl::PCLPointCloud2 ());

      // define a voxelgrid
      pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> voxelGrid;
      // set input to cloud
      voxelGrid.setInputCloud(cloudPtr);
      // set the leaf size (x, y, z)
      voxelGrid.setLeafSize(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
      // apply the filter to dereferenced cloudVoxel
      voxelGrid.filter(*cloud_filtered);   

      std::cerr << "PointCloud after filtering: " << cloud_filtered->width * cloud_filtered->height 
       << " data points (" << pcl::getFieldsList (*cloud_filtered) << ")." << std::endl;

      std::cin.ignore();
    }
    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>::SharedPtr subscription_;

};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Inside main function now" << std::endl;
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalSubscriber>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

Running it gives me below output.

```
Starting >>> custom_nav_stack_pkg
Finished <<< custom_nav_stack_pkg [16.4s]                       

Summary: 1 package finished [16.7s]
Inside main function now
[INFO] [1664396894.528685765] [minimal_subscriber]: I received the message , height is: '1'
[INFO] [1664396894.528876950] [minimal_subscriber]: I received the PCL message , height is: '1'
PointCloud before filtering: 15000 data points (x y z intensity ring time).
PointCloud after filtering: 5937 data points (x y z intensity ring time).

double free or corruption (out)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407071/double-free-or-corruption-(out)-error-with-pcl/) by [dvy](https://answers.ros.org/users/107873/dvy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2022-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a few changes needed to fix the error. The following should work:

```
void topic_callback(const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr msg_ptr) const
{
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloud_in_ptr(new pcl::PCLPointCloud2);
  pcl_conversions::toPCL(*msg_ptr, *cloud_in_ptr);

  RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_logger(), "[Input PointCloud] width " << cloud_in_ptr->width << " height " << cloud_in_ptr->height);

  pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloud_out_ptr(new pcl::PCLPointCloud2);
  pcl::voxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> voxel_grid;
  voxel_grid.setInputCloud(cloud_in_ptr);
  voxel_grid.setLeafSize(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
  voxel_grid.filter(*cloud_out_ptr);

  RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_logger(), "[Output PointCloud] width " << cloud_out_ptr->width << " height " << cloud_out_ptr->height);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dvy](https://answers.ros.org/users/107873/dvy/) on 2022-09-29**:
@rajivjoshi : Thanks a lot! It worked like a charm. By the way, can you please also explain the reason for the failure and the fix?

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-29**:
I am glad it worked. Notice that you are calling the class directly. Pay attention to the `()` after `PCLPointCloud2` . The `pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr` is a smart pointer, so you just need to provide the class name only, i.e., without `()`. Next, the `voxelGrid` filter requires smart pointer as input, so I created it at the beginning and used it inside `pcl_conversions::toPCL`. Notice the dereferencing of pointer here.